# Export Pivot Grid as Grid View to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress-mvc

So this may seem weird, but here is the situation I am currently dealing with.  The goal is to take data from a Pivot Grid and put it into a Grid View, then export that Grid View to Excel.

Currently there is a working version to build a Grid View out of the data pulled from the Pivot Grid, however, I lose the formatting that the Pivot Grid had when I build the Grid View.  My question is how would I capture that formatting out of the Pivot Grid, and how would I add it back into the Grid View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.  Here it is below.

```
gridSettings.SettingsExport.RenderBrick = (sender, e) =>
            {
                foreach (MVCxPivotGridField item in dataFields)
                {
                    if (e.RowType == DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GridViewRowType.Data
                        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.CellFormat.FormatString))
                        e.TextValueFormatString = item.CellFormat.FormatString;
                }
```

Grid Settings was my grid, and dataFields was the data from the Pivot Grid.  I just looped through the data and found where there was a format string for the Pivot Grid and then set the same format to the Grid View.
                };